# How to check if a dice set is correctly weighted?

Tags: balance, dice, weight

[image]
So let me give you a bit of backstory, I went to a friend's place to play DnD and I decided to put my solar powered dice to charge on top of my friend's standing lamp with the plastic box practically touching the lightbulb. The box , the d10 and the d12 were ruined but the rest seemd in good condition (and even still glowed).

The attached image is of the surviving dice, they seem to be fine on the outside, no bumps or warps apparent. The damaged die I left with my friend as a souvenir.

My concern now is that the remaining dice might have weight issues since they were still really hot when we salvaged them. Is there any reliable way to check if their weight distribution is still fine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I heard that a lot of people will "float" them. Get a glass of salt water, with enough salt to make the water dense enough to make the dice bouyant. Then float the dice and see if they just spin randomly, or if a certain side always turns to the top. I think it's an old golfer's trick.